# Weird lines shows everytime when I try making a Glass Object in blender

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, glass

[image: These weird lines]

I imported an object from maya and created a material in blender...and when i turn on the alpha blend option i get these wired lines every time.
I already tried flip normals ,recalculate normals , shade smooth , alpha hashed but these lines are still there

I want to export the file in glb format from blender and these lines are still showing up there
Here is the link for blender file

https://we.tl/t-OGJRmYd7JW

Comment: I tried following your instruction and got good result in blender Thanks.... but when exported in Glb format these are still visible.

Comment: Is this render engine problem or what?

Comment: Glass in Eevee needs tweaking, if you remove the Show Backface it will fix your problem but you won't see your own object by transparency, I hope someone has a proper answer

Comment: a hack would be to create a second object for the inner surface of your object, see Bibi's answer here (french, donwload his file): http://blenderclan.tuxfamily.org/html/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=50729&start=0#forumpost589337

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm not sure there's any perfect solution for your problem, but here is a trick proposed [here](http://blenderclan.tuxfamily.org/html/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=50729&forum=1) by Bibi.

If you disable the *Show Backface* option you'll get rid of the artefacts that you're talking about but you won't see the glass surfaces by transparency, so you still have a problem:

[image]

The trick is to separate your glass object in two separate objects, the outter and the inner surfaces...

[image]

and you'll get that, which is rather good:

[image]

the file is available here: [image]

Comment: Thank you so much this method solved my problem....

Answer (score 0):

change the blend mode of your material to alpha hashed.

Then you will get:

[image]

Comment: I changed the mode to alpha hashed and exported it in glb format(as i need glass object in Glb format) But these lines are still there

Comment: you didn't write anything in your question that you do export your file, and nothing about glb format. So you should improve your question....!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.... I improved my question